# Como guardar logs en volumen externo de un contenedor docker apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker

estoy utilizando la imagen de wordpress:6.4-apache, y necesitaría tener por defecto los logs de apache en una carpeta del host donde está levantado el contenedor para consultarlo por una herramienta externa.¿alguien me podría indicar como hacerlo? por defecto van a /dev/stderr.
Además necesitaría hacer el logrotate desde dentro del contenedor y veo que en el contenedor no está instalado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.